# Error while installing the libmtp library

Tags: windows-7, windows, libraries

When I'm running the configure file for the Libmtp library using Msys, everything seems to be going fine till I get an error that tells me that it can't find the Libusb library, I have installed it and its in the program files folder. It tells me to set the `LDFLAGS` environment variable to include it in the search path where I have it installed. Then it gives me an example which is:

```
setenv LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib.
```

But I'm on Windows so it would of course be a different directory. When I type the `setenv` command into msys it says command not found. How do I set the search path for minGW/msys?  I'm using Windows 7 64bit

Comment: It sounds like you do not have the paths set properly

Comment: I do not, that's why i asked.